# How to instal Beeline (Hive client) on a new RHEL server?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, beeline

I got a new server in the company and trying to figure out how to install Beeline without installing whole Hadoop package..

Tried following https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_jdbc_install.html  with `sudo yum install hive-jdbc` - but it says that there is no package `hive-jdbc`...

Where to find this package (or set of needed JARs) and what is the command to install/unpackage and open beeline first time?

Thanks